# Adding class to div at level above

Tags: jquery

im trying to set the panel heading to a different color by adding a class, if the panel body has any errors..

see my attempt which doesn't work....

any ideas?

```
 $(".input-validation-error").each(function () {

            $(this).closest('panel-default').find("panel-heading").addClass('panel-heading-error');

        });

    // rough HTML layout
        <div class="panel panel-default">
        ////stuff
           <div class="panel-heading">
           <div class="panel-body">
              <div class="input-validation-error"></div>
           </div>
        </div>
<div class="panel panel-default">
        ////stuff
           <div class="panel-heading">
           <div class="panel-body">

           </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're missing some period marks to denote class...
try:

`$(this).closest('.panel-default').find("div.panel-heading").addClass('panel-heading-error');`

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/0g10b5d6/

Comment: made no difference for me

Comment: I moved the closing div of your header around, as it doesn't seem logical to wrap the body in the heading, but here's a working example:   http://jsfiddle.net/0g10b5d6/

Answer (score -1):

You may use repeated ids then a simple method.
document.getElementById('Id'').class = "newClass";